# Why doesn't design view work on UWA dev in Visual Studio 2017 preview running on Server 2016

Tags: installation, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2016

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 preview and it **does allow** Win10 UWA (Universal Windows Apps) to be *created*, *edited*, *built* and *run* on Server 2016 (previously you couldn't).

However, for some reason the design preview doesn't work and gives the error:

> Visual Studio requires a newer version of Windows to display this
>   content. Please update to UAP 10.0.16299.0 or later.

As shown, in the snapshot, that version (of the Win10 SDK) is actually installed on my machine and was auto-installed when I installed VStudio 2017 preview.

Does anyone know why the design window doesn't work?

**Error Message Is Incorrect**

Also, notice that the error message is actually incorrect.  It says it needs a "newer version of Windows". Then it points me to a version of the win10 SDK.
That's confusing and/or mixed up.  Especially since that SDK is actually installed.

[image: required sdk installed but fails]

**EDIT**
I've also checked for System Updates but there do not seem to be any I'm missing:

[image: no updates]

Comment: Please make sure your OS is up-to-date, all pending windows patches already installed. Right click the project name, select 'Properties', choose different version for 'Target version' to test. To develop UWP, it is better to use windows 10, please check the VS 2017 system requirement: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs, there has one note "Universal Windows app development, including designing, editing, and debugging, requires Windows 10. Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2012 R2 may be used to build Universal Windows apps from the command line".

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I should've mentioned that I also checked for updates also and there were none available. Also I've seen that note you've mentioned and that conflicts with another item at : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30858/visualstudio2017-cannot-develop-uwp-on-windows-ser.html
It states: "We will no longer block opening UWP projects on Windows Server. Please look for it in an upcoming release. Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!"

Comment: Also, there seems to be a related issue with installing Win10 SDKs (the target SDK never seems to install properly) which I've documented at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/137393/visual-studio-community-2017-does-not-install-win1.html?childToView=137452#comment-137452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.0 Preview 4 released, it fixed this problem.

[image: VStudio about...]

After installing the update, I double-clicked the MainPage.xaml file and the Layout editor preview showed up on Server 2016.

However, I do have to have the project targeting the following win10 version 
[image: win10 version]

Targeting others doesn't seem to work properly.